# Glut + MPI_Send, actually not blocking

Tags: mpi, glut, blocking

I'm trying to communicate two different processes using MPI (MPMD communication). One of them uses GLUT to render some data that is generated based on the data sent by the other process.

My problem is that during the initialization phase the "consumer" (the one using GLUT) sends certain configuration data to the "producer", but it seems that the MPI_Send calls are not blocking. For example, I send 4 different messages from the consumer to the producer, each one with a different tag. It seems to work ok. Then I comment the first MPI_Send, without changing the code of the other process (that means that none of them should progress beyond the first MPI_Send and MPI_Recv, respectively). The problem is that the sender sends all the three messages and it seems that each MPI_Send returns MPI_SUCCESS since the tests that I do after each MPI_Send print messages corresponding to correct evolution. Meanwhile, the receiver does not progress.

I have tried to reproduce this behaviour in simpler applications, without GLUT, and they worked. But at the same time I see no reason for GLUT to cause this issues. Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that MPI_Send does not guarantee blocking, as stated in [1](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/sendmode.html), so in order to obtain the desired behavior I should use MPI_Ssend instead.

Comment: You are mistaking _synchronous behaviour_ with _blocking_.

Answer (score 1):

You have misread the semantics of the blocking MPI send mode. Blocking here means that the operation block until message data and its envelope have been safely stored away and the data buffer is free to be modified. In contrast, *non-blocking* operations (`MPI_I...`) return control immediately but require that you do not modify the data buffer while the operation is still in progress.

`MPI_Send` is the standard blocking send operation. It could be implemented as *synchronous* blocking send (`MPI_Ssend`) which does not return until the receive operation has been started or as internally *buffered* blocking send (similar to `MPI_Bsend`) which copies message data to a small internal buffer and returns back control. It is not defined by the standard how exactly the standard send is implemented. Most implementations buffer several short messages.